# Sequence that converge if they have an accumulation point

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, examples

I am looking for classes of sequence, that converge iff they contain a converging sub-sequence.

- The basic example of such sequences are monotone sequences of real numbers.
- A more interesting examples comes from metric fixed point theory:
  Let $B$ be a Banach space and $f\colon B \to B$ be a continuous mapping that is non-expansive (i.e. $\lVert f(x) - f(y)\rVert \le \lVert x -y\rVert$).
  Define $x_{n+1} := \frac{1}{2} x_n + \frac{1}{2} f(x_n)$ for any startingpoint $x_0\in B$.
  This is the so called *Krasnoselski iteration*.
  One can show that any accumulation point $\tilde{x}$ of $(x_n)$ is a fixed point of $f$.
  Since $f$ is non-expansive, it follows that
  $\lVert x_{n+1}-\tilde{x}\rVert = \frac{1}{2}\lVert (x_{n}-\tilde{x}) + (f(x_{n}) - f(\tilde{x}))\rVert\le \lVert x_n -\tilde{x}\rVert$.
  Hence $(x_n)$ converges iff it contains a converging sub-sequence.

  This is a special case of Ishikawa's fixed point theorem. (The Krasnoselski-Mann iteration - a generalization of the Krasnoselski iteration - also has this property.)

I am interested in this sequence because they provide very nice applications of the Bolzano-Weierstrass principle.

Do you know of any other examples of sequences with this property?
Do you know other proofs that uses this property together with the Bolzano-Weierstrass principle to prove the convergence of a sequence?

Comment: Much too trivial for an answer (perhaps even too trivial for a comment), but of course any Cauchy sequence has this property. (It had better be in a non-complete space, to be at least minimally interesting.)

Comment: This isn't quite what you're looking for, but the question reminds me of an interesting fact: a sequence converges to a point x if and only if for any subsequence, there's a sub-subsequence converging to x.

Comment: If you go beyond sequences, and to nets, then the ultranets satisfy this (and their analogue ultrafilters too): if there is a convergent subnet it is itself convergent.

Comment: @Henno: you are right - this even seems to hold for any ultra-limit and the sequence converging to it.
I was hoping for a more constructive way to find such sequences, but this is definitely an answer to the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following version of the mean ergodic theorem is taken from the book of Krengel, "ergodic theorems".

Let T be a bounded linear operator in a Banach space X. The Birkhoff averages are denoted by $A_n = {1\over n} \ \Sigma_{k=0}^{n-1} \ T^k$.
Assume that the sequence  of operator norms $||A_n||$ is bounded independently of $n$. Then for any x and y in B, the following is equivalent :

-- y is a weak cluster point of the sequence $(A_nx)$,

-- y is the weak limit of the sequence $(A_nx)$,

-- y is the strong limit of the sequence $(A_nx)$.

(note that we talk about cluster points instead of converging subsequences because we didn't assume B separable. Hence the weak topology is not necessarily metrizable.)

This theorem implies e.g. the ergodic theorem for Markov operators on $C(K)$ (sequential compactness follows from Azrela-Ascoli), or the ergodic theorem for power bounded operators defined on reflexive Banach spaces (sequential compactness follows from Eberlein-Smulian).

There is a whole set of theorems in ergodic theory along these lines.  Let me mention the convergence of the one sided ergodic [Hilbert transform](http://www.ee.bgu.ac.il/~guycohen/CCL.pdf), discussed in Cohen and Cuny (see Th 3.2) as another example.